# Destination array was not long enough

Tags: c#, arrays, list, backgroundworker, argumentexception

I have a List which is copied from another List, which throws an exception of "System.ArgumentException: Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds".

The exception thrown code is below,

```
List<myClass> tempCopy= new List<myClass>(tempList);
```

I have populated the tempList in a BackGround worker.

The reported issue occurs randomly, and doesnt happen all the time.

Could anyone please share me why this exception is thrown at random time?

Thanks and Regards,

Amal Raj.

Comment: A bit more code on how you populate your list in the background worker would be good. Seems to me that maybe your background worker is (sometimes) still running as you copy your list.

Comment: What's the type of `tempList`? Most likely it is being resized while the list constructor is copying it into `tempCopy`.

Comment: @Michael & Lee - Thanks for your responses. Yes i figured out that my background worker has not finished populating the tempList, so this exception is thrown.